# How to make sure that EJB timers run on single node at a time in clustered environment?

Tags: java, timer, ejb

I have created 4 different EJB timers using EJB 3.0. A single session bean is used for each timer ( I can not use EJB 3.1).
I start all timers using a a class which is configured in weblogic-application.xml as follow:

```
<wls:listener>
    <wls:listener-class>com.xyz.abc.TimerJob</wls:listener-class>
    </wls:listener>
```

This class TimerJob accesses a stateless session bean TimerServiceBean which internally create all timer jobs at the server startup.
I have configured TimerServiceBean and all Timer sesssion beans to have single instance only as follow:

```
<wls:weblogic-enterprise-bean>
        <wls:ejb-name>TimerServiceBean</wls:ejb-name>

        <wls:stateless-session-descriptor>
        <wls:pool>
        <wls:max-beans-in-free-pool>1</wls:max-beans-in-free-pool>
        </wls:pool>
</wls:stateless-session-descriptor>
```

This works fine in single server environment.
I deploy all this in clustered environment by following all steps mentioned in the artilce : http://shaoxiongyang.blogspot.in/2010/10/how-to-use-ejb-3-timer-in-weblogic-10.html

In clustered environment, the timers execute on each node
I want each timer to execute on single node after specific interval which I configured while creating timers.
Any suggestion in making them work on single node at a time. Thanks in advance for your valuable suggestions and replies.